# How to use SQL Server views with distinct clause to Link to a detail table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I may be total standard here, but I have a table with duplicate values across the records i.e. `People` and `HairColour`. What I need to do is create another table which contains all the distinct `HairColour` values in the `Group` of `Person` records.

i.e.

```
Name      HairColour
--------------------
Sam       Ginger
Julie     Brown
Peter     Brown
Caroline  Blond
Andrew    Blond
```

My `Person feature` view needs to list out the distinct `HairColours`:

```
HairColour Ginger
HairColour Brown
HairColour Blond
```

Against each of these `Person feature` rows I record the `Recommended Products`.

It is a bit weird from a Relational perspective, but there are reasons. I could build up the `Person Feature"`View as I add `Person` records using say an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger on the View. But it gets messy. An alternative is just to have `Person Feature` as a View based on a `SELECT DISTINCT` of the `Person` table and then link `Recommended Products` to this. But I have no Primary Key on the `Person Feature` View since it is a `SELECT DISTINCT` View. I will not be updating this View. Also one would need to think about how to deal with the `Person Recommendation` records when a `Person Feature` record disappeared since since it is not based on a physical table.

Any thoughts on this please?

**Edit**

I have a table of People with duplicate values for HairColour across a number of records, e.g., more than one person has blond hair. I need to create a table or view that represents a distinct list of "HairColour" records as above. Against each of these "HairColour" records I need link another table called `Product Recommendation`. The main issue to start with is creating this distinct list of records. Should it be a table or could it be a View based on a `SELECT DISTINCT` query?

So `Person` >- `HairColour` (distinct Table or Distinct View) -< `Product Recommendation`.

If `HairColour` needs to be a table then I need to make sure it has the correct records in it every time a `Person` record is added. Obviously using a View would do this automatically, but I am unsure whether you can can hang another table off a View.

Comment: Thanks Marc_s for the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need a table with a primary key that lists the distinct hair colors that are found in a different table.

```
CREATE TABLE Haircolour(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
Colour VARCHAR(50) NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_Haircolour] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID ASC))
```

Then insert your records.  If this is querying a table called "Person" it will look like this:

```
INSERT INTO Haircolour (Colour) SELECT DISTINCT HairColour FROM Person
```

Does this do what you are looking for?

UPDATE:

Your most recent Edit shows that you are looking for a many-to-many relationship between the Person and ProductRecommendation tables, with the HairColour table functioning as a cross reference table.

As ErikE points out, this is a good opportunity to normalize your data.

1. Create the HairColour table as described above.
2. Populate it from whatever source you like, for example the insert statement above.
3. Modify both the Person and the ProductRecommendation tables to include a HairColourID field, which is an integer foreign key that points to the PK field of the HairColour table.
4. Update Person.HairColourID to point to the color mentioned in the Person.HairColour column.
5. Drop the Person.HairColour column.

This involves giving up the ability to put free form new color names into the Person table.  Any new colors must now be added to the HairColour table;  those are the only colors that are available.

The foreign key constraint enforces the list of available colors.  This is a good thing.  Referential integrity keeps your data clean and prevents a lot of unexpected errors.

You can now confidently build your ProductRecommendation table on a data structure that will carry some weight.

Comment: I agree this is a step toward the best solution, but you haven't explained *why* this is beneficial or given any resources about normalization, constraints, and performance. Your script leaves the data in two disjoint tables that must be synchronized repeatedly--what happens when more HairColours are added--they won't be in the `HairColour` table.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I have added an edit to my question which might shed more light on it.

Comment: ErikE. Thanks for the reply. Yes I understand this Sync problem and that is why I am exploring the option of using a View with a Select Distinct. It might be totally wrong, but I feel I need to ask the question to check my thinking.

Comment: @ErikE You are correct that this table will not reflect new colors added to the Person table.  I previously posted an answer with a View that did so, but I did not understand OP's comments on that answer.  The latest Edit helps a lot:  obviously an xref table is required.  I will update my most recent answer.

Comment: +1. This is how databases should work. The application MUST be coded to add a new `HairColour` to the `HairColour` table before trying to use it. Additionally, using the `ID` is far superior (in my mind): smaller row size, proper normalization. Doing `SELECT DISTINCT` on the `HairColour` column would eventually be a huge performance bottleneck, scanning the entire table every time just to come up with a list of the valid values.

Comment: Thanks ErikE for this advice.

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply looking for a View of distinct hair colors?

```
CREATE VIEW YourViewName AS
SELECT DISTINCT HairColour 
FROM YourTableName
```

You can query this view like a table:

```
SELECT 'HairColour: ' + HairColour
FROM YourViewName
```

If you are trying to create a new (temp) table, the syntax would look like:

```
SELECT Name, HairColour
INTO #Temp
FROM YourTableName
GROUP BY Name, HairColour
```

Here the GROUP BY is doing the same work that a DISTINCT keyword would do in the select list.  This will create a temp table with unique combinations of "Name" and "HairColour".

Comment: Thanks for this. I am exploring other methods than creating a table of distinct "HairColour" records to which I can link the "Product Recommendation" records. Really not sure if it is possible to use a view. One would also need to compute a primary key which the "Product Recommendation" table would use. The advantage of using a DISTINCT VIEW is that it would auto update. However it might leave orphans in the "Product Recommendation" table.

Comment: @SamJolly I find it rather hard to understand what you are looking for.  I have added a second answer with a different approach.  Does that match what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear up a few things in your post (or in your mind) first:

1) What are the objectives? Forget about tables and views and whatever. Phrase your objectives as an ordinary person would. For example, from what I could gather from your post:
"My objective is to have a list of recommended products based on each person's hair colour."

2) Once you have that, check what data you have. I assume you have a "Persons" table, with the columns "Name" and "HairColour". You check your data and ask yourself: "Do I need any more data to reach my objective?" Based on your post I say yes: you also need a "matching" between hair colours and product ids. This must be provided, or programmed by you. There is no automatic method of saying for example "brown means products X,Y,Z.

3) After you have all the needed data, you can ask: Can I perform a query that will return a close approximation of my objective?
See for example this fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fda0d6/1

I have also defined your "Select distinct" view, but I fail to see where it will be used. Your objectives (as defined in your post) do not make this clear. If you provide a thorough list in Recommended_Products_HairColour you do not need a distinct view. The JOIN operation takes care of your "missing colors" (namely "Green" in my example)

4) When you have the query, you can follow up with: Do I need it in a different format? Is this a job for the query or the application? etc. But that's a different question I think.